# Cannot insert values into access 97 using Ucanaccess 3.0.6. It shows access is read only

Tags: java, sql, ucanaccess, ms-access-97

Cannot insert values into access 97 using Ucanaccess 3.0.6. It shows access is read only. Error: UCAExc:::3.0.6 Access 97 is supported in read-only. Is there any solution for inserting values to access 97 db in java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line of the [Ucanaccess feature list](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) says:

> Supported Access formats: 2000, 2002/2003, 2007, 2010/2013/2016 databases. (Access 97 format supported for read-only.)

Comment: is there any other free jar files available for access 97?

Comment: Sorry, asking for external references is off-topic.